# How to get corresponding file in another folder in Octave/MATLAB?

Tags: octave

In one of my folders (say Folder01) there are files like "IGN_A.txt", "IGN_B.txt", "IGN_C.txt".........

In another folder (say Folder02) there are files like "sim_IGN_A_M01.txt", "sim_IGN_A_M02.txt", "sim_IGN_A_M03.txt" for the corresponding file "IGN_A.txt" in Folder01.

Similarly, "sim_IGN_B_M01.txt", "sim_IGN_B_M02.txt", "sim_IGN_B_M03.txt" for corresponding file "IGN_B.txt" in Folder01.

How can I get the corresponding files from those Folders. 
For example, I want to get "IGN_A.txt" along with "sim_IGN_A_M01.txt", "sim_IGN_A_M02.txt", "sim_IGN_A_M03.txt". 
Here. I added my code which can only get "IGN_A.txt" along with "sim_IGN_A.txt".

```
Folder01 = 'Home/A1';
Folder02 = 'Home/A2';
%Going Throuh all the Folder01 files
Allfiles_Folder01 = dir(fullfile(Folder01, '*IGN*.txt'));

for k = 1:length(Allfiles_Folder01)
    fullFileName = fullfile(Folder01, Allfiles_Folder01(k).name);
    READ_Folder01=dlmread(fullFileName,'',2,0);


    fullFileName_Sim = fullfile(Folder02, strcat('sim_',Allfiles_Folder01(k).name))
    READ_Folder02=dlmread(fullFileName_Sim,'',1,0);
end
```

Comment: You need `fileparts` and `fullfile`, and also simple concatenation.

Comment: Can you make changes in my code? I tried it in different way but couldn't manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the naming convention is consistent as provided by you, this would be my suggestion:

```
% Get all filenames from Folder01 in cell array.
Allfiles_Folder01 = dir(fullfile(Folder01, '*IGN*.txt'));
Allfiles_Folder01 = {Allfiles_Folder01.name}

% Iterate all filenames from Folder01.
for k = 1:numel(Allfiles_Folder01)

  % Cut file extension from current filename.
  filename = Allfiles_Folder01{k};
  filename = filename(1:end-4);

  % Get all filenames from Folder02 with specific search string in cell array.
  Allfiles_Folder02 = dir(fullfile(Folder02, strcat('*', filename, '*.txt')));
  Allfiles_Folder02 = {Allfiles_Folder02.name}

  % Do stuff with filenames from Folder02 corresponding to filename from Folder01.
  % ...
  % ...

end
```

Comment: Use `glob` if you want a cell array of filenames, don't expect that file extensions are always 3 chars

Comment: @Andy You're right, thanks for your hint. I haven't paid attention to that, since I assumed, that there'll be only `txt` files.

Comment: btw, there is `fileparts` to split dir, filename and extension (I should have mentioned that before in my comment)